# Setting up Redux toolkit with Next js 14.0.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

Been running into a couple of issues trying to setup reduxt toolkit in next 14 as see n below. i've followed the exact steps on several youtube videos and articles online. but stil getting stuck here as i can't wrap my head around what seems to be the issue
[image]

when it get's compiled by next on the frontend i get this error
[image]

and this is the store.ts file
[image]

Comment: Rather than screenshot of the code, please consider pasting the code itself with ``` 3 back ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file needs a `.tsx` extension, not a `.ts` extension.

Answer (score 6):

In next.js, you have to créate a providers file, and import it for using in layout.
Something like this:

```
// Providers.js
    'use client';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";
import { Providers } from "@/Redux/provider"

export function Providers({ children }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

Now in your layout.js, import and use it:

```
 import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { Providers } from "@/Redux/provider"


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Your App",
  description: "This is a example for use redux in next.js versión 13 >=",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Providers store={store}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </Providers>
  );
}
```

In the example, I créate a folder Redux for settings and files.

I hope to help you. =)

Answer (score 2):

For Next.js with App Router with Redux Toolkit (Next 13 and 14).

Error : Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.

Solution :

Create file providers.tsx :

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400272/setting-up-redux-toolkit-with-next-js-14-0-1
'use client';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "@/store";

export function Providers({ children } : { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

Include providers.tsx in layout.tsx.

layout.tsx:

```js
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import { store } from '@/store'
import { Providers } from './providers'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <Providers>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
    </Providers>

  )
}
```

Explanation :
By default, Next.js(13 &14) uses Server Components.
This Solution allows you to create a "Client Components" wrapper of Redux Toolkit's Provider.
Because Use State and Lifecycle Effects aren't disponible with Server Components.